# How to change the model of an ASP .Net MVC Kendo Chart using javascript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the kendo UI MVC wrapper to create a chart. The chart is using a model:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<ModelA>()
....
```

I wish to change the model used by the chart and reload using a new datasource. I am changing the datasource in javascript like this:

```
....
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/Controller/_ChartData",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataID
            }
     }
 });
```

This is firing on a button click to reload the data. The data is reloading correctly. Is this the correct way to change the datasource and how do i change the model that the chart is using (ModelA -> ModelB)

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the dataSource...

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
                url: "/Controller/_ChartData",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataID
            }
        }
    }, 
    schema: {
        model: {
            // ModelB details go here
        }
    });
```

Have a look at [the Kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes - this is possible but the schema must be added as field name: type, field name: type etc. This information is already in my model so i was wondering if it is possible to pass the model in rather than recode the model in the jQuery function (in the same way that it is passed in to the wrapper function originally)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: when i create the chart using the wrapper the syntax is: @(Html.Kendo().Chart<ModelA>()...etc
I want to modify the chart by using ... schema:{model:{ ModelB}}

Comment: If the whole of the model is changing, then I have to say I'd be tempted to have the thing all managed in the JS depending on the model and just instantiate the chart each time.